# DidselectionItemAt not being called when there's a uibutton inside a collection view

Tags: swift

When I have a UIButton inside a Collection View, the didselectItemAt is not being called. How can I fix it. See the code below:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if let cell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath) as? Category2Cell {
        cell.button.setBackgroundImage(UIImage.init(named: "getStarted"), for: .normal)
        recommends.append((cell.button.titleLabel?.text!)!)
        print("select \(recommends)")
        cell.isSelected = true
    }
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didDeselectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if let cell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath) as? Category2Cell {
        cell.button.setBackgroundImage(UIImage.init(named: "whitebox"), for: .normal)
        recommends = recommends.filter(){$0 != cell.button.titleLabel?.text!}
        print("deselect \(recommends)")
        cell.isSelected = false
    }
}
```

Here's my colletionView

```
final class Category2Cell: UICollectionViewCell {
    private enum Constants {
        // MARK: contentView layout constants
        static let contentViewCornerRadius: CGFloat = 8.0

        // MARK: imageView layout constants
        static let buttonHeight: CGFloat = 48.0

        // MARK: Generic layout constants
        static let verticalSpacing: CGFloat = 8.0
        static let horizontalPadding: CGFloat = 16.0
        static let profileDescriptionVerticalPadding: CGFloat = 8.0
    }


    let button: UIButton = {
        let button = UIButton(frame: .zero)
        button.setTitleColor(UIColor.black, for: .normal)
        button.titleLabel?.font = UIFont(name: "CeraPro-Regular", size: 15)
        button.setBackgroundImage(UIImage.init(named: "whitebox"), for: .normal)
        return button
    }()
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: I'm wondering if `button.isExlusitveTouch = false` would fix it, allowing the cell view to be touched, and then the delegate method to be triggered... Else, you could use a callback on the button action method to trigger the delegate method yourself...

Answer (score 1):

If you wish your collection view Did Select will call, for that disable the user interaction for the button.

if you wish your button click event will also work then, please add the addTarget method of that button with its selector method.